# The elimination rules for propositional equality

Tags: logic, type-theory

I am learning propositional equality from an [nlab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/propositional+equality).

The article states that the elimination rules for propositional equality is as follows:

$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash A \; \mathrm{type} \quad \Gamma, x:A, y:A \vdash P(x, y) \; \mathrm{prop}}{\Gamma \vdash \left(\forall x:A.P(x, x)\right) \implies \left(\forall x:A.\forall y:A.x =_A y \implies P(x, y)\right) \; \mathrm{true}}$$

I do not know why $P$ is binary. I think the rule required is "if $P(a)$ is true and $a=b$ then $P(b)$ is true".

Can't I just write the elimination rules for propositional equality the following way?

$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash A \; \mathrm{type} \quad \Gamma, x:A\vdash P(x) \; \mathrm{prop} \quad \Gamma\vdash a:A \quad \Gamma\vdash P(a) \; \mathrm{true} \quad \Gamma\vdash b:A \quad \Gamma\vdash a=_A b \; \mathrm{true}}{\Gamma \vdash P(b)\; \mathrm{true}}$$

Comment: "every type A has a binary relation according to which two elements x and y of A 
 are related if and only if they are equal" This is not (according to nLAB) the so-called [judgmental equality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/judgmental+equality).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mentioned is usually called the substitution rule. And it's fine for logic in general. But if you want to get into categorical logic you need something that fits better with categorical notions.

In this case you get that the equality is left adjoint to contraction. Let me explain a bit further.

---

Assume that for each list of variables you can construct the set of all formulas that depend on those variables. Call that $P(xs)$ where $xs$ is a list of variables.

Now $P$ is actually a functor $:Var \rightarrow HA$ where $HA$ is the category of Heyting algebras and their corresponding morphisms. And you may think of what I wrote $Var$ as $FinSet$ or $\mathbb N$ or whatever implementation you like.

An important detail about this, is that we don't mean free variables exactly. The formula $x=y$ can be thought of as depending only on $x$ and $y$, or depending also on another variable say $z$, and as many as we wanted, as so happens with functions.

---

Consider a map in $Var$ that sends the list $[x,y]$ to the list $[x]$. Call it $\pi$.

Now what happens when we send $\pi$ through $P$?

We get that $P\ \pi : P\ [x,y] \rightarrow P\ [x]$.

Given a formula that depends on $x$ and $y$, $P\ \pi$ lets us think of it as applied to $x$ twice. i.e: $\varphi(x,y) \mapsto \varphi(x,x)$. Called a "contraction".

---

What would a left adjoint to it look like?

$$(P\ [x,y])\big(L\ \varphi(x) , \psi(x,y)\big)
\cong
(P\ [x])\big(\varphi(x) , P\ \pi\ \psi(x,y)\big)$$

Remember we are in $HA$ here so arrows are "proofs" which I'll write as $\vdash$, and functors that map these arrows as proof trees, as is usual.

Let $L\ \varphi(x) :\equiv \varphi(x)\land x=y$.

If we pick $\varphi(x) :\equiv \top$ we get

$$\dfrac{\vdash \psi(x,x)}{x=y \vdash \psi(x,y)}$$

which semantically is exactly the same as what you have. (Here it actually goes not only from top to bottom of the tree but also from bottom to top, but you can deduce one from the other anyway.)

---

Hope this helps, feel free to ask anything if I went too quickly at some point.

Comment: This answer has some errors. $P$ should be contravariant for this specification of $Var$. $Pπ$ then takes $Γ ⊢ φ$ to $Γ, x ⊢ φ$, where $x$ is unused in $φ$ (this is weakening). The operation that takes $φ(x,y)$ to $φ(x,x)$ is _contraction_, and corresponds to $δ (Γ,x) = (Γ,x,x)$. Equality is left adjoint to contraction.

Comment: @DanDoel Thanks for the clarification! I know what you mention is usually what is done. However, where does what I say fail?

Comment: Weakening is an operation $P\ [x] → P\ [x,y]$, and is adjoint to quantifiers. The operation that lets you apply a variable twice (and to which equality is adjoint) is contraction, not weakening. To present $P$ as covariant in $Var$, the usual way is to say that a map $Γ → Δ$ picks an element of $Δ$ for each element of $Γ$. Then weakening (here) is given by the map $[x] →[x,y]$ that maps $x$ to $x$, and contraction by the map $[x,y] → [x]$ that maps both $x$ and $y$ to $x$.

Comment: Thanks. Edited.